# SQL Function to Search in String Values

Tags: sql-server

I would like to create function on sql server to check in string values .

pass to two parameters first original  `'12.33.44.65.22'` , second  `'44.22'` and return

`true` if `parameter2` is found in `original parameter` 
ex :

```
call fun1('22.34.56.78' , '23.24')  -- return false 
call fun1('22.34.56.78' , '23.24') -- return false 
call fun1('22.34.56.78.43.76' , '22.12') -- return false , because should be both exists 
call fun1('22.34.56.78' , '22.56') -- return true 
call fun1('21.34.56.54' , '21.56') -- return true 
call fun1('21.34.56.54' , '34.56') -- return true 
call fun1('22.34.56.78' , '34.55.35') -- return false
```

Thanks.

Comment: call fun1('22.34.56.78' , '23.24')  -- return false 
call fun1('22.34.56.78.43.76' , '22.12')  -- return  false , because should be both exists
call fun1('22.34.56.78' , '22.56')  -- return  true
call fun1('21.34.56.54' , '21.56')  -- return true
call fun1('21.34.56.54' , '34.56')  -- return true
call fun1('22.34.56.78' , '34.55.35')  -- return false

Comment: Which version of SQL Server?

Comment: sql server 2008

Comment: Welcome as a new user to SO. Please take the [Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and also read [Help-Center/asking](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Instead of using comments for code you should edit your question to enhance the information.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the updated question, this isn't the answer. You're looking to confirm that all values in string of delimited values exists in another string of delimited values, in this case the delimiter is '.'

```
select 
  case when charindex('44.22','12.33.44.65.22')>0 then 'true' 
    else 'false' 
    end
```

Update: if the search string is always in that format, this will work:

```
create function dbo.func1 (@StringToFind nvarchar(128), @StringToSearch nvarchar(128))
returns nvarchar(5) as
begin
  return case 
          when charindex(left(@StringToFind,charindex('.',@StringToFind)-1),@StringToSearch)>0 
           and charindex(right(@StringToFind,charindex('.',reverse(@StringToFind))-1),@StringToSearch)>0 
          then 'true' 
          else 'false' 
          end;
end
go

select dbo.func1('44.22','12.33.44.65.22')
```

Comment: in this case should be return true because 44.22 is already exitis in (12.33.44.65.22)

Comment: @Bas fair enough but you didn't state this in the original question. You should edit that and provide more details, like are their any limitations to the second expression? Can it be 22.35.45.6999.23 etc....

Comment: if i pass one parameter  like select dbo.func1('44','12.33.44.65.22')
I have error

Comment: both parameter is dynamic

Comment: this was assuming the search strings would always be that format 'xx.xx', 'xx.xx.xx....' for something more dynamic you can adapt and use @Shnugo's answer

Answer (score 0):

```
Declare @YourTable table (TheString varchar(100), FindString varchar(100));
Insert Into @YourTable values
 ('22.34.56.78','23.24')       -- return false 
,('22.34.56.78.43.76','22.12') -- return false , because should be both exists 
,('22.34.56.78','22.56')       -- return true 
,('21.34.56.54','21.56')       -- return true 
,('21.34.56.54','34.56')       -- return true 
,('22.34.56.78','34.55.35');

Select *
      ,InString = [dbo].[udf_InString](TheString,FindString)
From @YourTable
```

Returns

```
TheString           FindString  InString
22.34.56.78         23.24       false
22.34.56.78.43.76   22.12       false
22.34.56.78         22.56       true
21.34.56.54         21.56       true
21.34.56.54         34.56       true
22.34.56.78         34.55.35    false
```

The UDF

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[udf_InString](@String varchar(max),@Search varchar(max))
Returns varchar(25)
Begin
    Declare @RetVal varchar(25)
    ;with cte as (
        Select RetSeq = Row_Number() over (Order By (Select null))
              ,RetVal = LTrim(RTrim(B.i.value('(./text())[1]', 'varchar(max)')))
        From (Select x = Cast('<x>'+ Replace(@String,'.','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml).query('.')) as A 
        Cross Apply x.nodes('x') AS B(i)
    )
    Select @RetVal = case when count(*)>0 then 'true' else 'false' end
     From  cte A
     Join  cte B on (A.RetSeq+1=B.RetSeq or A.RetSeq+2=B.RetSeq)
     Where A.RetVal+'.'+B.RetVal = @Search
    Return @RetVal
End
```

Answer (score 0):

You might try it like this:

I use an XML-trick first to split both delimited strings into their parts (get a *derived table*). An `INNER JOIN` reduces them to the parts included in both sides. The rest is counting: If the count of common elements equals the total count on side 2, all elements are common:

**Attention: Any row, where no common elements exist, is ommitted**. You might use a `LEFT JOIN` against a `DISTINCT` list of all existing IDs to inlcude rows without value crossings...

It **should be easy to create a function from this**. Just hand in the two strings as parameters and replace `TheString` and `CheckString` with them (and delete `FROM @dummyTbl`). In this case an empty result is `false`.

```
DECLARE @dummyTbl TABLE(ID INT IDENTITY,TheString VARCHAR(100), CheckString VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @dummyTbl VALUES
 ('22.34.56.78','23.24')  -- return false 
,('22.34.56.78.43.76','22.12') -- return false , because should be both exists 
,('22.34.56.78','22.56') -- return true 
,('21.34.56.54','21.56') -- return true 
,('21.34.56.54','34.56') -- return true 
,('22.34.56.78','34.55.35');

WITH casted AS
(
    SELECT ID
          ,CAST('<x>' + REPLACE(TheString,'.','</x><x>') + '</x>' AS XML) AS s1
          ,CAST('<x>' + REPLACE(CheckString,'.','</x><x>') + '</x>' AS XML) AS s2
    FROM @dummyTbl
)
,s1Tbl AS
(
    SELECT ID,x.value('.','int') Val 
    FROM casted
    CROSS APPLY s1.nodes('/x') AS A(x)
)
,s2Tbl AS
(
    SELECT ID,x.value('.','int') Val 
    FROM casted
    CROSS APPLY s2.nodes('/x') AS A(x)
)
SELECT s1Tbl.ID
      ,CASE WHEN COUNT(s1Tbl.ID)=(SELECT COUNT(x.ID) FROM s2Tbl AS x WHERE x.ID=s1Tbl.ID) THEN 'true' else 'false' END AS FullyIncluded
FROM s1Tbl
INNER JOIN s2Tbl ON s1Tbl.Val=s2Tbl.Val AND s1Tbl.ID=s2Tbl.ID
GROUP BY s1Tbl.ID
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a function that uses XML to spit the strings and an anti-join to see if everything matches.  Then you can simply call it as a cross apply like below.

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.FindStringsInString(
    @String VARCHAR(MAX)
    ,@SearchString VARCHAR(MAX)
)
RETURNS BIt
AS
BEGIN
    IF (COALESCE(LEN(@String),0) = 0 OR COALESCE(LEN(@SearchString),0) = 0)
    BEGIN
       --either the String or the SearchString is Null or Empty
       RETURN 0
    END

    DECLARE @XMLString XML = CAST('<X>' + REPLACE(@String,'.','</X><X>') + '</X>' AS XML)
    DECLARE @XMLSearchString XML = CAST('<X>' + REPLACE(@SearchString,'.','</X><X>') + '</X>' AS XML)

    IF NOT EXISTS (
       SELECT 1
       FROM
          (
          SELECT
             n.value('.', 'varchar(MAX)') as S
          FROM
             @XMLSearchString.nodes('X') as t(n)) searchstring
          LEFT JOIN (
          SELECT
             n.value('.', 'varchar(MAX)') as S
          FROM
             @XMLString.nodes('X') as t(n)) string
          ON searchstring.S = string.S
       WHERE
          string.S IS NULL
    )
    BEGIN
       --All of the values in the Search StringMatch a Value in the String
       RETURN 1
    END

    --default if it hasn't returned by now it is false
    RETURN 0

END
GO
```

Test Data, I added NULL and '' cases and Select from function:

```
DECLARE @Table AS TABLE (String VARCHAR(100), SearchString VARCHAR(100))
INSERT INTO @Table VALUES
('22.34.56.78' , '23.24')  -- return false 
,('22.34.56.78' , '23.24') -- return false 
,('22.34.56.78.43.76' , '22.12') -- return false , because should be both exists 
,('22.34.56.78' , '22.56') -- return true 
,('21.34.56.54' , '21.56') -- return true 
,('21.34.56.54' , '34.56') -- return true 
,('22.34.56.78' , '34.55.35') -- return false
,('22.34.56.78' , NULL) -- return false
,('22.34.56.78' , '') -- return false
,(NULL , '34.55.35') -- return false
,('' , '34.55.35') -- return false

SELECT *
FROM
    @Table t
    CROSS APPLY (SELECT
       dbo.FindStringsInString(t.String, t.SearchString)) s(Match)
```